# ADO Search Performance

Tags: performance, vb6, ado

Because I am not familiar with ADO under the hood, I was wonder which of the two methods of finding a record generally yields quicker results using VB6.

1. Use a 'select' statement using 'where' as a qualifier.  If the recordset count yields zero, the record was not found.
2. Select all records iterating through records with a client-side cursor until record is found, or not at all.

The recordset is in the range of 10,000 records and will grow.  Also, I am open to anything that will yield shorter search times other than what was mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every case I can think of, selecting using the where clause is faster.

Even in situations where the client code will iterate through the whole database (file-based databases like Access, for example), you will have optimized code written in c or c++ doing the selection (in the database driver.)  This is always faster than VB6.

For Database engines (SQL, MySQL, etc), the performance increase can even be more profound.  By using the where clause, you limit the amount of data that must be transmitted over the network, vastly improving the response.

Some additional performance tips:

- Select only the fields you want.
- Build indexes on frequently used fields
- Watch what kind of recordset you are returning.  Use Forward-only cursors if you are just returning data from a database.

Lastly, I was shocked by VB.NET's database performance, it being several times faster than the fastest VB6 code.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM foo WHERE some_column='some value'
```

If the result is greater than 0 the record satisfying your condition was found in the database. It is unlikely you would get any faster than this. Proper indexes on the columns you are using in the `WHERE` clause could considerably improve performance.